# how to print "ds" and "abc" from the string s("lkjhgfdsabc")?

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program that prints the substrings of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. For example, if s = 'lkjhgfdsabc', then your program should print

Comment: What does that mean, "output from a string"?

Comment: what that means *output "ds" and "abc" from a string like"lkjhgfdsabc"*? Are you looking to check if `"ds"` is a substring of another string and if so print it?

Comment: Getting closer, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import re

def foo(search_string):
    pattern1 = "ds"
    pattern2 = "abc"
    match1 = re.match(pattern1, search_string)
    match2 = re.match(pattern2, search_string)

    if (match1 && match2):
        print(match1.group() + " " + match2.group()
    else:
        print("strings not found")
```

This checks if the strings are in the main string and prints them out if both are found. If I understood you correctly, this should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```py
def alphabetical(string):
    saved = ""
    for i in string:
        if saved:
            if i > saved[-1]:
                saved += i
            else:
                if len(saved) > 1:
                    print(saved)
                saved = i
        else:
            saved += i
    if len(saved) > 1:
        print(saved)
```